# Removing dashes in a Java string and capitalizing the character after the dash

Tags: java, string

I have a String `nba-west-teams blazers` and I want to convert the string into a format like `nbaWestTeams blazers`. Essentially, I want to remove all the dashes and replace the characters after the dash with it's uppercase equivalent.

I know I can use the String method replaceAll to remove all the dashes, but how do I get the character after the dash and uppercase it?

```
// Input
String withDashes = "nba-west-teams blazers"

String removeDashes = withDashes.replaceAll(....?)

// Expected conversion
String withoutDashes = "nbaWestTeams blazers"
```

Comment: You'll probably have to use a more advanced concept like Matcher.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: You could first search all indices of *dashes* and then first replace the symbols after them with their upper-case variant, after that remove all *dashes*. You could also do this more elegant with **regex** or stuff like that. For the manual part `String#indexOf` and `String#toUpperCase` will be very helpful, or just use a `Matcher` with `Matcher#find` (essentially the same but more elegant).

Comment: Hint: you do some prior research ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) and the [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) method of the StringBuilder class. StringBuilder allows fast editing of Strings.
When you are finished use [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString()).

If you need more help just make a comment.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly to use these functions to solve the problem, ideally providing some code? To maximise the long-term value of this answer, it's better to have it be a detailed answer to the question instead of just pointing OP in the right direction.

Comment: Of course, i will provide the full code after dinner, if not somebody answers it before me ;)

Comment: And now you already have two wonderful answers. I like both ones, however be careful that your string never look like this "foo-" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Patterns with regex like this `\-([a-z])`:

```
String str = "nba-west-teams blazers";
String regex = "\\-([a-z])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    str = str.replaceFirst(matcher.group(), matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
}

System.out.println(str);//Output = nbaWestTeams blazers
```

---

So it will matche the first alphabets after the dash and replace the matched with the upper alphabets

Comment: `replaceFirst` would be slightly more efficient, although, for really long strings, you should probably opt for [an O(n) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45535380/1711796) instead of this O(n^2) solution.

Comment: thank you @Dukeling this is correct i already edit my answer, and about the optimization i agree with you i will try to make something better

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the string and when a hyphen is found, just skip the hyphen and transform the next character to uppercase. You can use a `StringBuilder` to store the partial results as follows:

```
public static String toCamelCase(String str) {
    // if the last char is '-', lets set the length to length - 1 to avoid out of bounds
    final int len = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == '-' ? str.length() - 1 : str.length();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(len);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == '-') {
            ++i;
            builder.append(Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i)));
        } else {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Misses to uppercase the first character.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string at the space and use https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#caseformat to convert the dashed substring into a camel cased string.